# Regression: finding p-value and F

Tags: regression, self-study, p-value, f-test

I'm working on stats homework, and I've come across a problem I cannot figure out. It's a multi-part problem, and I've correctly answered a number of the questions, but there are a few that are not coming up right.

Problem:

> Healthy bones are continually being renewed by two processes. Through bone formation, new bone is built; through bone resorption, old bone is removed. If one or both of these processes is disturbed, by disease, aging, or space travel, for example, bone loss can be the result. Tartrate resistant acid phosphatase (TRAP) is a biochemical marker for bone resorption that is also measured in blood. The data below gives values for this biomarker and a measure of bone resorption `VO--`. Analyze these data using the questions in the previous exercise as a guide. (Give answers accurate to 2 decimal places.) [Data](https://www.webassign.net/mintrostat/data/10_13/data1.dat)
>
> Analyze these data using the logs of both TRAP and `VO--`.
>   Run the regression using TRAP to predict `VO--`. Summarize the results. (Round your answers to two decimal places.)
>   $\log($VO--$) = \mathbf{5.62} + .42 \cdot \log($TRAP$)$
>   $F = \mathbf{1590.97}$
>   $P = \mathbf0$
>   $R^2= .1$

I wasn't quite sure how to figure out the answers, but I entered the data into list 3 and list 4 on my TI-83 calculator. Then I entered `ln(L3)` into list 1 and `ln(L4)` into list 2. From there, I did `STAT > TESTS > LinReg(a+bx)` to get the regression equation: $y = 5.62 + .42x$ and $R^2= .1$. I input these numbers, and the $R^2$ and slope were correct, but the $y$-intercept was not. I then used `STAT > TESTS > ANAOVA(L1, L2)` to get $F = 1590.97$ and $P = 0$, but neither of those answers were correct. I've listed my answers above with incorrect answers bold. Can anyone help let me know what I'm doing wrong? I'd be very appreciative!

Comment: What you're doing wrong is using a calculator to solve your problem. The calculator is a tool. If you don't know how to do this question by hand with a smaller data set of say 5 points, you should start from there.

Comment: R gives 5.618 and 0.416 (to 3dp) for the intercept and slope; if those are incorrect (i.e. if rounding isn't the issue), you might need to double check that there's not an error in the data. However, the ANOVA analysis you've asked for compares the means of your X and Y, it doesn't do the F for the line; that's certainly not what you want.